# How to map url to static csv file in django?

Tags: python, django, csv

I want to build a django application. Normally, we should map every url to a view and in the view map to a html page or return some data back to front-end. But how can I map a url directly to one csv file in my project. and this url directly return this csv file to the front-end. Suppose I have a file in my project folder, named /external_files/mydata.csv.

One way I can do is to map the url to a view and in the views, it loads the csv, and sends the csv in the http, if we can send the csv file in http not json or xml. But this is not convenient way.

Comment: To download a file as an attachment, we have to change the Content-Disposition header. To manipulate the header we will need a view. Or you could probably use your web server(nginx/apache) to do this.